# Differential Equation $2x+y^2+2 xy y'=0 -> x^2+xy^2=c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my math book I have to calculate the solution for this differential equation.

[image]

The solution should be:

[image]

And to be honest i don't know how to get started with this.

Comment: I edited the title as that equation was not matching with the equation in your post.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the equation is **exact**?

Comment: @imranfat you're right sorry the title was correct though

Answer (score 1):

${d\over dx}(y^2x)=y^2+2xy{d\over dx}y$. This implies that $2x+y^2+2xy{d\over dx}y={d\over dx}(xy^2)+2x=0$. We deduce that $xy^2=-x^2+c$ and $xy^2+x^2=c$.

Comment: I made a mistake in the formula, it should be this [formula](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?&space;2x+y%5E2+2%5Ctext%7Bxy%7D%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7Dy=0)